# Ruby on Rails checkbox doesn't change value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, checkbox

I'm using **'form for'** to send form information and I have a few categories (in my db, they are boolean). To confirm information about categories I use checkbox. But it is not working and I can't understand why.

```
<%= form.label :lifehacks, "Lifehacks" %>
<%= form.check_box :lifehacks, :class => 'checkbox-in-create-post' %>
```

And when I go to console and view created post - category "Lifehacks" is false (what is default value). And it's not changing even if checkbox is checked.

But interesting fact: the same code for other category:

```
<%= form.label :photos, "Photos" %>
<%= form.check_box :photos, :class => 'checkbox-in-create-post' %>
```

if checkbox is checked is changing category "Photos" boolean to true.

If you need some addition information - tell me.

Can you tell me where I've made my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to permit the `lifehacks` parameter in the controller so is not updated. Look for `params.require(something).permit(:photos, etc...)` and add your missing `lifehacks` parameter in the list of permitted attributes.

Comment: Geez, thnx a lot. Stupid of me.